# Does Selenium webdriver (Java) support to test php pages? Cannot identify css selectors

Tags: java, php, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm testing a website written in php language. I'm automating the test contents of number of clicks in the page, so using Selenium web driver (Java one), using cssSelector to identify the elements, but it is not working when executing the script:

```java
WebElement element = 
 driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector(
  ".view-dom-id-d21931301746‌​656c32fcf49fd08a0005 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(4)"
 )
);
element.click();
```

I have tried using an xpath too. My question here is, whether cssSelector or xpath can be used to find the element in php?

Comment: What exactly is not working? You need to show the code you're using.

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".view-dom-id-d21931301746656c32fcf49fd08a0005 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(4)"));
element.click();  This is what not working

Comment: I guess it is not able to find the element. Are you sure .view-dom-id-d21931301746‌ is a valid css class? Maybe you should try xpath too.

Comment: tried relevant xpath too. My question here is, whether cssSelector or xpath  can be used to find the element in php?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the language is. When the page is loaded, it generates an HTML in the browser. As long as the element is available it should be found. Maybe the website uses ajax to load that data/element and when you open it with selenium this element is not loaded yet. Try setting a delay before finding the element.

Comment: Mate, I've tried that too... not working. I'm using the selenium webdriver for Java, Should I get the Selenium webdriver for PHP to test PHP code?

Comment: No need to. You use Java driver because your selenium is in Java. Is it an online website? Can you post the link to the page you're trying to test?

Comment: Hi AJ ano, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I have taken the liberty of editing your question to include the further information you posted in the comments; remember, on this site you are encouraged to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear, understandable and useful as possible.

Comment: The same code is working fine currently, there were some ads on the page, and once I've added add blocker plugin, this seems working, ran several times to conclude. Thanks Vince for the edit, and this question can be closed now. Also, Thanks Mohammad Amin!